# hot to iterate through checkboxes placed in groupbox in proper order i.e from first to last c# windows form application

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

```
     cs.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SEATING", cs);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
        {

                reader.Read();
                CheckBox temp = (CheckBox)c;
                int seat = reader.GetInt32(0);
                int status = reader.GetInt32(2);

                if (status == 1 && seat == Convert.ToInt32(temp.AccessibleName))
                {
                    temp.Checked = true;
                    temp.Enabled = false;
                }


        }
```

this is my code for iterating through checkbox placed in groupbox,
but it iterates in reverse order from last to first
can anyone help to make it iterats from first to last

Comment: how is the order specified? by the tabindex? by the name? how do you define first and last?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not sure it works, I didn't test it):

```
    cs.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SEATING", cs);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                     .OrderBy(a=> a.TabIndex))        
    {

            reader.Read();
            CheckBox temp = (CheckBox)c;
            int seat = reader.GetInt32(0);
            int status = reader.GetInt32(2);

            if (status == 1 && seat == Convert.ToInt32(temp.AccessibleName))
            {
                temp.Checked = true;
                temp.Enabled = false;
            }


    }
```